# Why can I see duplicate vote numbers with the flagging dialog as a < 3K user?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

When flagging to close a question for being a duplicate, you can see the numbers cast to each candidate in question:

[image]

This seems like a bug to me. I cannot see the close vote numbers for any other reason, so why can I see these numbers?

Comment: To save you time searching for the question it's a dupe of.

Comment: @DannyBeckett I agree with showing the questions, but not the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Meh.

Firstly, with some clever AJAX, you *can* see the close vote tallies. I don't see any bad outcomes of showing it in the flag dialog.

The numbers in the dupe menu include flags, not just VTCs. It can help you choose an appropriate duplicate. I think that's useful.